# Managing requests between .jsps and servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a project that makes use of both .jsps and servlets. I'm having difficulties in forwarding requests between two files: a registration form(jsp) and a registration servlet. The servlet validates data received through the form and also handles user creation. The servlet should also notify the .jsp if any errors occur during registration. I am trying to use JSTL tags in order to do this, but upon registration the user is not redirected nor notified by the servlet.

**register.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" session="true"contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
            ... 
        <div class="content">
            <h2 class="form">Register</h2>
            <form action="Register" method="post">
                <p>
                    User name: <br /> <input type="text" name="username" /> <b> <c:out
                            value="${messages['userName']}" />
                    </b> <br /> First Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="fist_name" />
                    <b> <c:out value="${messages['firstName']}" />
                    </b> <br /> Last Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="last_name" />
                    <b> <c:out value="${messages['lastName']}" />
                    </b> <br /> Email Address: <br /> <input type="text" name="email" />
                    <b> <c:out value="${messages['email']}" />
                    </b> <br /> Password: <br /> <input type="password" name="password" />
                    <b> <c:out value="${messages['password']}" />
                    </b> <br /> Retype password: <br /> <input type="password"
                        name="password2" /> <b> <c:out
                            value="${messages['password2']}" />
                    </b> <br /> <b> <c:out value="${messages['password3']}" />
                    </b> <br /> <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </p>
            </form>

            <!-- end .content -->
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p align="center">&copy; Books Point 2013</p>
            <div align="center">
                <!-- end .footer -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end .container -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The servlet is as follows:

**Register.java**

```
import books.pointejb.User;
import books.pointejb.UserViewBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ValidateLoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Validate Register Servlet", urlPatterns = {
        "/Register", "/Register.do" })
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int MAX_LEN = 30;
    private static final int MIN_LEN = 6;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get request parameters for username and password
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
        String pwd2 = request.getParameter("password2");
        boolean ok = true;
        // Validate parameters and forward them to the ejb
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (user != null) {
            // Validate user name
            if (user.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("userName", "Please enter username");
                ok = false;
            } else if (!user.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]$")) {
                messages.put("userName",
                        "Invalid username. The username should contain only aplhanumerical values");
                ok = false;
            } else if (user.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("userName",
                        "Invalid username. Username should not be more than "
                                + MAX_LEN + " characters");
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        if (firstName != null) {
            // Validate first name
            if (firstName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("firstName", "Please enter your first name");
                ok = false;
            } else if (!firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")) {
                messages.put("firstName",
                        "Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                ok = false;
            } else if (firstName.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("firstName",
                        "Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                                + " characters long");
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        if (lastName != null) {
            // Validate last name
            if (lastName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("lastName", "Please enter your last name");
                ok = false;
            } else if (!lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")) {
                messages.put("lastName", "Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                ok = false;
            } else if (lastName.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("lastName",
                        "Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                                + " characters long");
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        if (email != null) {
            // Email is specified as request parameter, do the business logic
            // here.
            if (email.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("email", "Please enter email");
                ok = false;
            } else if (!email
                    .matches("([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)")) {
                messages.put("email", "Invalid email, please try again.");
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        if (pwd != null) {
            // Validate password
            if (pwd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("password", "Please enter password");
                ok = false;
            } else if (pwd.length() < MIN_LEN && pwd.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("password",
                        "Invalid password. It must have at least " + MIN_LEN
                                + " characters, but not more than " + MAX_LEN);
                ok = false;
            }
            if (pwd2 != null) {
                // Validate password
                if (pwd2.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    messages.put("password2", "Please enter password");
                    ok = false;
                } else if (pwd2.length() < MIN_LEN && pwd2.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                    messages.put("password2",
                            "Invalid password. It must have at least "
                                    + MIN_LEN
                                    + " characters, but not more than "
                                    + MAX_LEN);
                    ok = false;
                } else if (!pwd2.equals(pwd)) {
                    messages.put("password3", "Passwords do not match");
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
            if (!ok) {
                // Put messages in request scope so that it's accessible in EL
                // by
                // ${messages}.
                request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
                // Forward request to JSP for display.
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,
                        response);
            } else {
                // Send data to ejb
                UserViewBean userBean = Lookup.doLookupUser();
                User registerUser = new User();
                // Set the username
                registerUser.setUsername(user);
                // Set the first name
                registerUser.setFirstName(firstName);
                // Set last name
                registerUser.setLastName(lastName);
                // Set email
                registerUser.setEmail(email);
                // Set the password(the bean computes the hash as well)
                registerUser.setPassword(pwd);
                // Now we try to register the new user. Additionally we log him in.
                if (userBean.register(registerUser)) {
                    // Add a session variable based on the local date, remote
                    // address,
                    // remote port
                    // and username if the provided credentials(user/pass) are
                    // valid
                    String sessionData = now();

                    sessionData = sessionData + " " + request.getRemoteAddr();
                    sessionData = sessionData + " " + request.getRemotePort();
                    sessionData = sessionData + " " + user;

                    String generatedSession = null;
                    try {
                        // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
                        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                        // Add password bytes to digest
                        md.update(sessionData.getBytes());
                        // Get the hash's bytes
                        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
                        // This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
                        // Convert it to hexadecimal format
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                            sb.append(Integer.toString(
                                    (bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                        }
                        // Get complete hashed password in hex format
                        generatedSession = sb.toString();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Get the request session and set new variables
                    request.getSession().setAttribute(cookieid,
                            generatedSession);
                    // Also store cookie in a safe place(the cookie jar)
                    CookieJar.userCookie = generatedSession;
                    // Send the request back with the session set
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,
                            response);
                } else {
                    // Code to be executed if registration goes wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private static final String cookieid = "CookieId";
        ...
}
```

Although the servlet sets attributes and forwards them to register.jsp the page does not show the error messages upon invalid input.

**Edit:**

```
import books.pointejb.User;
import books.pointejb.UserViewBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ValidateLoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Validate Register Servlet", urlPatterns = {
        "/Register", "/Register.do" })
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int MAX_LEN = 30;
    private static final int MIN_LEN = 6;
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    private static final String LOG = "books_point_log.txt";
    private PrintWriter logThis = null;


    private void InitLog() {
        try {
            logThis = new PrintWriter(LOG, "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("[I] Exception " + e.toString() + " \n Stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("[I] Exception " + e.toString() + " \n Stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get request parameters for username and password
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
        String pwd2 = request.getParameter("password2");
        boolean ok = true;
        // Validate parameters and forward them to the ejb
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Initialize output file
        if(DEBUG) {
            InitLog();
        }
        if (user != null) {
            // Validate user name
            if (user.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("userName", "Please enter username");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("userName Please enter username");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (!user.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]$")) {
                messages.put("userName",
                        "Invalid username. The username should contain only aplhanumerical values");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("userName Invalid username. The username should contain only aplhanumerical values");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (user.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("userName",
                        "Invalid username. Username should not be more than "
                                + MAX_LEN + " characters");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("userName Invalid username. Username should not be more than "
                                    + MAX_LEN + " characters");
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (firstName != null) {
            // Validate first name
            if (firstName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("firstName", "Please enter your first name");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("firstName Please enter your first name");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (!firstName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")) {
                messages.put("firstName",
                        "Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("firstName Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (firstName.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("firstName",
                        "Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                                + " characters long");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("firstName Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                            + " characters long");
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (lastName != null) {
            // Validate last name
            if (lastName.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("lastName", "Please enter your last name");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("lastName Please enter your last name");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (!lastName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$")) {
                messages.put("lastName", "Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("lastName Invalid name. Use alpha values only.");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (lastName.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("lastName",
                        "Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                                + " characters long");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("lastName Invalid name. Name should be at most " + MAX_LEN
                            + " characters long");
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (email != null) {
            // Email is specified as request parameter, do the business logic
            // here.
            if (email.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("email", "Please enter email");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("email Please enter email");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (!email
                    .matches("([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)")) {
                messages.put("email", "Invalid email, please try again.");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("email Invalid email, please try again.");
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (pwd != null) {
            // Validate password
            if (pwd.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("password", "Please enter password");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("password Please enter password");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (pwd.length() < MIN_LEN || pwd.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("password",
                        "Invalid password. It must have at least " + MIN_LEN
                                + " characters, but not more than " + MAX_LEN);
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("password Invalid password. It must have at least " + MIN_LEN
                            + " characters, but not more than " + MAX_LEN);
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (pwd2 != null) {
            // Validate password
            if (pwd2.trim().isEmpty()) {
                messages.put("password2", "Please enter password");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("password2 Please enter password2");
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (pwd2.length() < MIN_LEN || pwd2.length() > MAX_LEN) {
                messages.put("password2",
                        "Invalid password. It must have at least " + MIN_LEN
                                + " characters, but not more than " + MAX_LEN);
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("password2 Invalid password. It must have at least " + MIN_LEN
                            + " characters, but not more than " + MAX_LEN);
                }
                ok = false;
            } else if (!pwd2.equals(pwd)) {
                messages.put("password3", "Passwords do not match");
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("password3 Passwords do not match");
                }
                ok = false;
            }
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (!ok) {
            // Put messages in request scope so that it's accessible in EL
            // by
            // ${messages}.
            request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
            // Forward request to JSP for display.
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,
                    response);
        } else {
            // Send data to ejb
            UserViewBean userBean = Lookup.doLookupUser();
            User registerUser = new User();
            // Set the username
            registerUser.setUsername(user);
            // Set the first name
            registerUser.setFirstName(firstName);
            // Set last name
            registerUser.setLastName(lastName);
            // Set email
            registerUser.setEmail(email);
            // Set the password(the bean computes the hash as well)
            registerUser.setPassword(pwd);
            // Now we try to register the new user. Additionally we log him in.
            if (userBean.register(registerUser)) {
                // Add a session variable based on the local date, remote
                // address,
                // remote port
                // and username if the provided credentials(user/pass) are
                // valid
                String sessionData = now();

                sessionData = sessionData + " " + request.getRemoteAddr();
                sessionData = sessionData + " " + request.getRemotePort();
                sessionData = sessionData + " " + user;

                String generatedSession = null;
                try {
                    // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                    // Add password bytes to digest
                    md.update(sessionData.getBytes());
                    // Get the hash's bytes
                    byte[] bytes = md.digest();
                    // This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
                    // Convert it to hexadecimal format
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                        sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,
                                16).substring(1));
                    }
                    // Get complete hashed password in hex format
                    generatedSession = sb.toString();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Add log operation to log file
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("User " + registerUser.getUsername() + " successfully registered");
                }
                // Get the request session and set new variables
                request.getSession().setAttribute(cookieid, generatedSession);
                // Also store cookie in a safe place(the cookie jar)
                CookieJar.userCookie = generatedSession;
                // Send the request back with the session set
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request,
                        response);
            } else {
                // Code to be executed if registration goes wrong
                if(DEBUG) {
                    logThis.println("Failed to register user " + registerUser.getUsername());
                }
            }
        }
        // close logfile
        if(DEBUG) {
            logThis.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the **getServletConfig** method was only a stub. Removing/commenting this method

```
public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
if (!ok) {
```

seems to be inside the

```
if (pwd != null) {
```

block.

So it will only execute if `pwd != null`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, when the end user registers the URL directs to the /Register servlet and hangs there(there are no redirects or notifications of any kind suggesting whether the registration was successful or not)

Comment: @Sebi I recommend you either run the web application in debug mode or add a bunch of log statements. If the registration is meant to fail, it's possible the code won't get into either of the blocks that uses the `RequestDispatcher` to `forward`. There are a lot of possible execution paths that would lead to that. Debugging the servlets will show you which.

Comment: I've added logging support(see the edited code). Strangely, my log file is not even created. I tried setting up a break point at the beginning of the doPost() method but execution apparently doesn't reach this method. Upon registration I get a blank page with the URL site/Register

Comment: Should the logfile be created in the same directory where Register.class is?

Comment: @Sebi No, the file will be created in the folder that `java` process was started in. Just give it an absolute path.